# Term that describes when only one option was requested, but more were offered

Tags: word-choice

Which term describes that in a scenario where only one option or result is requested, but multiple are being offered, which might be perceived badly by the requester?

Example:

> Q: I'm looking for a word that describes a scenario where one option is requested, but multiple ones are offered. Do you know such a word?
>   A: Yes, there are WORD_1 and WORD_2.
>   Q: But I was only interested in WORD_1, why do you suggest also WORD_2?

Exceptional case that requires further specification of the original request, denial of the complete result or choice.

Comment: I only wanted one. I only need one. One is enough. Thank you, one will do. One's plenty. Thanks, just one is fine. (Is that too many?)

Comment: Are you looking for a *solitary* word?

Answer (score 1):

A polite way to refer to unwanted or excessive answers would be to thank the supplier for their *effusive* answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from a *[surfeit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/surfeit)* of opportunity

> An excessive amount of something [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Or a *[plethora](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/plethora)* of potentialities

> A large or excessive amount of (something) [*ditto*]

A colloquial phrase is *enough already* (or in Italian, *basta!*)

Answer (score 1):

The word you may be looking for is [supererogatory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/supererogatory):

> more than is needed, desired, or required

(The Free Dictionary)